# How to calculate the square root without using library and built-in methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqrt

Please help me to write a function to compute the square root of positive real numbers using the formula:

```
x i+1 = (1/2) * (xi + (A / x1)),
```

where 'A' - input real number.

On the zero iteration next statements have been taken x0 = A
The error should be at least  10-6

Output

```
sqrt (2) = 1.414
sqrt (9) = 3
sqrt (25) = 5
```

Comment: `Math.sqrt` isn't a "library method", it's built-in...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could take x<sub>i</sub> (`x`) and the new value of x<sub>i + 1</sub> (`x1`) and check if the values are equal. Then end the series and return that value.

For starting, you need an apporopriate value like the half of the given value.

```js
function sqrt(a) {
    var x,
        x1 = a / 2;
        
    do {
        x = x1;
        x1 = (x + (a / x)) / 2;
    } while (x !== x1);
    return x;
}

console.log(sqrt (2)); // 1.414
console.log(sqrt (9)); // 3
console.log(sqrt (25)); // 5
```

Comment: thank U for help! Can U explain why did U use DO...WHILE but not WHILE?

Comment: because you need first a new value and then the check.

Comment: This function causes a **timeout** error when `a` is zero **0**. Use `if (a === 0) return a;`.

Comment: @csr-nontol, you can edit the answer, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use bisection - a more general method for solving problems:

```
var sqrt = function(n) {
    if (n<0) {
        throw "are you kidding?! we are REAL here.";
    }
    if (n === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    var bisect = function(l,r) {
        var avg = (l+r)/2;
        if (r-l<0.00000001) {
            return (l+r)/2;
        }
        if (avg*avg > n) {
            return bisect(l, avg);
        } else if (avg*avg < n) {
            return bisect(avg, r);
        }
    }
    return bisect(0, n < 1 ? 1 : n);
}
```